# Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of a finite extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

In my commutative algebra course we learned about the Gelfand-Krillov dimension. This is the definition:
$\newcommand{\GK}{\mathsf{GKdim}}$
Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra of finite type and $V$ a $K$-vector subspace of $A$ of finite dimension such that $A=K[V]$. The Gelfand--Kirillov dimension of $A$ is defined as:
$$\GK(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_2(\text{dim}_K(K+V+\dots+V^n))}{\log_2(n)}$$

We also proved that this dimension coincides with the Krull dimension (because we are in the commutative case) and, as a corollary to this, we have the following trivial result:

Let $B\left/A\right.$ be a finite extension of finitely generated $K$-algebras. Then $\GK(A)=\GK(B)$.

That is indeed a trivial result using the fact that Gelfand--Kirillov and Krull dimension are equal. My question is whether there is a relatively easy proof of this corollary just using the definition. My guess is that this is possible, but since this is quite a difficult definition I don't know how to start.

This is what my intuition tell me we should do:

Of course $A$ is f.g. so we can find $V$ such that $A=K[V]$ and $B\left/A\right.$ is finite, so we should be able to find $W$ such that $B=K[V+W]$. From this, if we can prove that there is some $N(n)$ such that for every $n$:

$$K+V+\dots+V^n\subset K+(V+W)+\dots+(V+W)^n\subset K+V+\dots+V^{N(n)}$$
Then we are done.

Maybe none of this steps are correct and this has no sense, but this is the only idea I have.

Edit: I would also like if you could recommend me a good book covering the Gelfand--Kirillov dimension.

Comment: Notice the difference between $\mathsf{GK}$-$\dim(A)$ and $\mathsf{GK}-\dim(A)$. The hyphen in $\LaTeX$ does not work like a hyphen in text, but like a minus sign. Notice also that $\LaTeX$ has its own command for dimension: it is ```\dim```.

Comment: It suffices to do it for $\dim W=1$, i.e. $B = A[y]$. In this case, $\dim B_n = \sum_{i=0}^n \dim A_i$ since $y$ has weight $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your $\LaTeX$ correction.  But I dont urderstand you. I got why you can assume $\dim W=1$. But, what is $B_ n$ and $A_i$?

Comment: I am assuming $A$ (and thus $B$) is weight graded, but maybe you don't want this?

Comment: If posible I would prefer a more elementary solution, but maybe this is not posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first reduce to a simpler case, since $B/A$ is finite, we can break it up into iterated extensions, each dominated by extensions of the type $A'\subset A'[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, for $f(x)$ monic of finite degree with coefficients in $A'$:

$$A\subset A[x_1] \subset A[x_1,x_2] \subset ... A[x_1,..x_n]=B$$

So it suffices to prove the claim in this case, since the dimension can only get smaller when we map onto these subrings. Now let this (monic) polynomial be $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i x^i$ with $a_i\in A$. If $V$ is our subspace generating $A$, consider the generating subspace of $A$:

$$V'=V+\text{span}_K(a_i)_{i=0}^{k}$$

And the following subspaces of $B$:

$$S=\text{span}_K(x^i)_{i=0}^{k-1}$$
$$W=V'+S$$

Then note that we have $S^2\subset V'S$, since products of $x^i$ have coefficients in $V'$, so we have $$W^2=(V')^2+V'S$$ In general, we have $$W^n=(V'+S)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n (V')^{n-i}S^i= (V')^n+(V')^{n-1}S$$
By repeated applications of $S^2\subset V'S$.

But now our subspace $S$ had finite dimension $k$, and $1$ was in $V'$, so $(V')^{n-1}\subset (V')^{n}$, so we have the bound of: $$\dim W^n\leq (k+1)(\dim V')^n$$ Then, since the $GK$ dimension can be computed with respect to any generating subspace, we get our desired bound, since the $k+1$ vanishes in this limit.

If one wanted to avoid that corollary of the main theorem, that $GK$ dimension is independent of the generating subspace $V$ chosen, a similar method to the above can be used to show this directly, add elements to your subspace one at a time.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question, why you can assume the extension is of that form? Why it cant'thappen that the extension is of the form $A'\subset A'[x]/\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle$ or of the form $A'\subset A'[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ with $f(x)$ non monic?

Comment: It suffices to show for any element $x$ of $B$, you can find a monic polynomial $f$ with $A$ coefficients such that $f(x)=0$. For this, note that the submodule generated by all the $x^i$ in $B$ is finitely generated (since $B$ is finite over $A$, and $A$ is Noetherian), so find the first $x^n$ expressible in terms of lower $x^i$, and rearrange that to get a monic polynomial. It might not be true that the map from $A[T]/f(T)$ onto $A[x]$ is an isomorphism, but its surjective, so we are fine.

Comment: So the extension in total can be more complicated, but by picking one element at a time we get a finite chain of extensions that admit a surjective map from extensions of this simple form, and chaining these equalities together gives the result.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand everything.